# Using mutate_at with prefix column names to compare values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with old & new values. I need to update new values if something changed. I think I am really close, but I can't find the missing piece **using tidyverse**. With base R - using a for loop -  it works, but I don't want to create new objects or overwrite the existing one.

```
data <- tribble(~id, ~firstname, ~lastname, ~old_firstname, ~old_lastname,
    1, NA, NA, "Peter", "Busch",
    2, NA, "Trochen-Pflaume", "Hans", "Trocken")


data%>%
mutate_at(vars(firstname, lastname), ~case_when(
is.na(.) & !is.na(str_c("old_",.)) ~ str_c("old_", .)),
!is.na(.) & . != str_c("old_",.) ~ .)
```

Basically, the only thing to check is whether the new value is empty, then the old value should be taken. As a result, more complex case_when queries are planned. But I fail to manipulate the column name within the mutate_at function.

What I want, but it depends on the case_when:

```
  tribble(~id, ~firstname, ~lastname, ~old_firstname, ~old_lastname,
            1, "Peter", "Busch", "Peter", "Busch",
            2,"Hans", "Trochen-Pflaume", "Hans", "Trocken")
```

Thx for the help!

Comment: This is a really good question and I am excited to see a tidyverse answer showing how to correctly use non-standard evaluation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I recently found a more concise approach using `purrr::reduce`, so I add it to my old answer below:

```r
library(tidyverse) 

data <- tribble(~id, ~firstname, ~lastname, ~old_firstname, ~old_lastname,
                1, NA, NA, "Peter", "Busch",
                2, NA, "Trochen-Pflaume", "Hans", "Trocken")

# your data
data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id firstname lastname        old_firstname old_lastname
#>   <dbl> <lgl>     <chr>           <chr>         <chr>       
#> 1     1 NA        <NA>            Peter         Busch       
#> 2     2 NA        Trochen-Pflaume Hans          Trocken

# First, we still need a helper function, this time using `mutate` and not `transmute`:
recode_vars <- function(df, x) {      
  mutate(df, 
            !! x := case_when(  
              is.na(!! sym(x)) & !is.na(!! sym(paste0("old_",x))) ~ as.character(!! sym(paste0("old_", x))),
              (!is.na(!! sym(x)) & !! sym(x) != !! sym(paste0("old_",x))) ~ as.character(!! sym(x))
            )
  ) 
} 

# Then, we need the variable names as strings in a vector:
var_ls <- c("firstname", "lastname")

# Now, we can use `purrr::reduce` in a pipe with `.init = .` (referring to your data):
data %>% 
  reduce(var_ls, recode_vars, .init = .)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id firstname lastname        old_firstname old_lastname
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>           <chr>         <chr>       
#> 1     1 Peter     Busch           Peter         Busch       
#> 2     2 Hans      Trochen-Pflaume Hans          Trocken
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Old answer

This is a challenging question. I am using a workaround for similar problems, but I haven’t yet found a way that works using `mutate_at`. The problem with `mutate_at` is that I do not know how to access the name of each variable. In a “normal” `mutate/case_when` or  `transmute/case_when` call you define `!! x :=` and can then access the variable name with `!! sym(x)` and derivate names of your variable with `!! sym(paste0(“someprefix_”, x))`.

This is how your problem would be solved with a custom `transmute/case_when` function:

```r
recode_vars <- function(df, x) {      
  transmute(df, 
         !! x := case_when(  
           is.na(!! sym(x)) & !is.na(!! sym(paste0("old_",x))) ~ as.character(!! sym(paste0("old_", x))),
           (!is.na(!! sym(x)) & !! sym(x) != !! sym(paste0("old_",x))) ~ as.character(!! sym(x))
         )
  ) 
} 

# Define here the variable names you want to recode
var_ls <- c("firstname", "lastname")

bind_cols(map_dfc(var_ls, ~ recode_vars(data, .x)),
          select(data, -var_ls)) %>% 
          select(id, everything())
```

With `map_dfc` you get a data frame with all your newly recoded columns and then you need to column bind them back to your old data frame while dropping the old columns – which is working, but it’s not smooth and does not happen in a pure dplyr pipeline.

I wonder whether there is a more consice way using `mutate_at` instead of my approach above.

Comment: Thx a lot. Seems great, will test it tomorrow and give feedback. The !! notation is new to me

Comment: If the `!!` notation is new to you I recommend [this vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). It’s not totally up to date, but covers the basics.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I had to finish the project first and so I used the loop. Your way seems to work at first sight! Many thanks for that. I will test it again and deal with the !! notation.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `na.locf` from `zoo` package?

```
library(zoo)

data <- data.frame(t(apply(data[,c(2,4)],1,function(x) na.locf(x,fromLast = T))),
                     t(apply(data[,c(3,5)],1,function(x) na.locf(x,fromLast = T))))
data <- data[,c(1,3,2,4)]
```

output:

```
> data
  firstname        lastname old_firstname old_lastname
1     Peter           Busch         Peter        Busch
2      Hans Trochen-Pflaume          Hans      Trocken
```

Comment: Mit working, because it's a lot of columns & i would like to use the prefix for the matching. But thanks for the help